# How to use a tensorflow tensor value in a formula?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a quick question. I am developing a model in tensorflow, and need to use the iteration number in a formula during the construction phase. I know how to use global_step, but I am not using an already existing optimizer. 
I am calculating my own gradients with

```
grad_W, grad_b = tf.gradients(xs=[W, b], ys=cost)
grad_W = grad_W +rnd.normal(0,1.0/(1+epoch)**0.55)
```

and then using

```
new_W = W.assign(W - learning_rate * (grad_W))
new_b = b.assign(b - learning_rate * (grad_b))
```

and would like to use the epoch value in the formula before updating my weights. How can I do it in the best way possible? I have a sess.run() part and would like to pass to the model the epoch number, but cannot directly use a tensor.
From my run call

```
_, _, cost_ = sess.run([new_W, new_b ,cost], 
      feed_dict = {X_: X_train_tr, Y: labels_, learning_rate: learning_r})
```

I would like to pass the epoch number. How do you usually do it?

Thanks in advance, Umberto

**EDIT**:

Thanks for the hints. So seems to work

```
grad_W = grad_W + tf.random_normal(grad_W.shape, 
      0.0,1.0/tf.pow(0.01+tf.cast(epochv, tf.float32),0.55))
```

but I still have to see if that is what I need and if is working as intended. Ideas and Feedback would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `epoch` as a non-trainable `tf.Variable` in your graph and increment it at the end of each epoch. You can define an operation with [`tf.assign_add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) to do the incrementation and run it end of each epoch.

Instead of `rnd.normal` you will also need to use [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) then.

Example:

```
epoch = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False) # 0 is initial value
# increment by 1 when the next op is run
epoch_incr_op = tf.assign_add(epoch, 1, name='incr_epoch')

# Define any operations that depend on 'epoch'
# Note we need to cast the integer 'epoch' to float to use in tf.pow
grad_W = grad_W + tf.random_normal(grad_W.shape, 0.0,
                                  1.0/tf.pow(1+tf.cast(epoch, tf.float32), 0.55))

# Training loop
while running_epoch:
    _, _, cost_ = sess.run([new_W, new_b ,cost], 
       feed_dict = {X_: X_train_tr, Y: labels_, learning_rate: learning_r})

# At end of epoch, increment epoch counter
sess.run(epoch_incr_op)
```

Comment: Good one. Thanks. I tried but I get the error ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Tensor' and 'float'``` from the line ```grad_W = grad_W + rnd.normal(0,1.0/(1+epochv)**0.55)``` (I used epochv since epoch was already used as variable)

Comment: @Umberto it seems that `tf.pow` which is called for `**` [needs both its arguments to be of the same type](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7170). Now they are an integer and a float. This should be fixed by casting `epoch` to float: `tf.cast(epoch, tf.float32)`. Updating answer.

Comment: Almost but not quite :-) I am now getting ```ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.```...

Comment: @Umberto Ah... Perhaps `tf.pow` should be explicit then? `tf.pow(tf.cast(epoch,tf.float32), 0.55)` -- sorry, don't have access to a running tensorflow instance now so I'm kind of guessing here.

Comment: You are more than nice. Thanks for the ideas! I get the same valueError with this ```grad_W = grad_W + rnd.normal(0,1.0/tf.pow(1.0+tf.cast(epochv, tf.float32),0.55))```

Comment: @Umberto -- is `rnd.normal` a Numpy function or generic Python function by any chance? Generally you cannot mix TF graph ops with python without some special arrangements. You proably need to replace with [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal) ?

Comment: Check my EDIT. What do you think?

Comment: @Umberto Looks good to me and technically works if your aim indeed is to perturb your gradients by adding to them some random independently normally distributed noise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166263/discussion-between-umberto-and-mikkola).